# Rational curves on ruled surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, rational-curves

Let $S$ be a ruled surface (over an algebraically closed field) with an $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle $\pi\!: S \to E$ onto an elliptic curve $E$. What is the classification of (possibly singular) irreducible rational curves on $S$? Are they only fibres of $\pi$?

Comment: Composing the map of the rational curve with the map $\pi$ gives a rational curve mapping to an elliptic curve, hence a constant map. So the map has image inside a fiber.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand your idea. Can you clarify it please?

Comment: Suppose we have a map from a rational curve to an elliptic curve. Normalize the rational curve, so assume it is smooth. The elliptic curve has a nowhere vanishing section of its canonical bundle. Composing with the differential of the map, we get a section of the canonical bundle on the rational curve. But the degree of the canonical bundle of any smooth rational curve is negative. So the section vanishes everywhere. So the differential of the map is zero, i.e. a constant map.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Ben McKay's argument only works in characteristic 0. But it is always true that if you have a non-constant map $X \to Y$ of smooth projective curves, the genus of $X$ is at least equal to the genus of $Y$; see Example 2.5.4. in Hartshorne.